# Is this an application of the mean value theorem?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I have this problem and I was thinking to use the mean value theorem, but in the hypothesis i don't have the conditions (explicitly at least). Any ideas of how to start?

> Suppose that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = 0$, and that exist $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{1}{f'(x)}$. Show that exist an open interval with center in $a$ such that in that interval but without the $a$ $f(x)≠0$.

Comment: I suspect when they say that the limit exists, they specifically refer to a finite limit.

Comment: @saulspatz In that case $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{1}{f'(x)}$ won't exist

Comment: @Lui Can you please write the question properly. I cannot understand what the question exactly wants to say.

Comment: @Rakesh Bhatt Something like this: Suposse: $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = 0$ and that exist $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{1}{f'(x)}$. Prove that exist an open Interval with center in a, something like: $(a-r,a+r)$ such that for a $x\in(a-r,a)\cup(a,a+r)$ $f(x)≠0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proof idea which uses the MVT, or rather just its special case known as Rolle's Theorem.

Assume that for every $\epsilon >0$, there is $x\in (a, a+\epsilon)$ with $f(x)=0$.

Then for every $\epsilon$, there are actually infinitely many such $x$ (why?). Choose two of them, $x_{1,\epsilon}$ and $x_{2,\epsilon}$. By Rolle's Theorem (fill in details), $f'(x) = 0$ somewhere in the interval $(x_{1,\epsilon}, x_{2,\epsilon})$ which is contained in $(a, a+\epsilon)$. This holding for every $\epsilon$ contradicts the existence of $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{1}{f'(x)}$ (why?).

So there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $f$ has no zero between $a$ and $a+\epsilon$. Completely analogously, find an interval to the left of $a$ without zeros of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Since the limit of $1/f'$ exists the derivative $f'$ is non-zero in some deleted neighborhood of $a$ and therefore by intermediate value property it maintains a constant sign on each side of $a$ in this deleted neighborhood. Thus $f$ is strictly monotone on each side of $a$ in the deleted neighborhood. And since $f(a) =0$ it follows that $f$ is non-zero in the deleted neighborhood of $a$.